# I am trying to parse this json i don't know what i am doing wrong here

Tags: google-chrome, go

```
type RedisConfig struct {
    Dev struct {
        Host    string `json:"host"`
        Port    int    `json:"port"`
        PodHost string `json:"pod_host"`
        PodPort int    `json:"pod_port"`
    } `json:"dev"`
    Stage struct {
        Host    string `json:"host"`
        Port    int    `json:"port"`
        PodHost string `json:"pod_host"`
        PodPort int    `json:"pod_port"`
    } `json:"stage"`
    Prod struct {
        Host    string `json:"host"`
        Port    int    `json:"port"`
        PodHost string `json:"pod_host"`
        PodPort int    `json:"pod_port"`
    } `json:"prod"`
} 

var  jsonFile  =  `{
  "dev": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 63713219,
    "pod_host":"127.0.0.1",
    "pod_port":131
  },
  "stage": {
    "host": "123.1.1.",
    "port": 6379,
    "pod_host":"21321321",
    "pod_port":6379
  },
  "prod": {
    "host": "21321321321",
    "port": 6379,
    "pod_host":"f.com,
    "pod_port":6379
  }
}`  


data,err := json.Unmarshal(jsonFile,RedisConfig{})
```

I am trying to parse this JSON I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Please help I have started working on go a few days back

Comment: There is a typo, making the whole JSON document invalid: `"pod_host":"f.com,` is missing the closing quotation mark.

Comment: still, I am facing the issue @colm.anseo

Comment: 1. you need to pass a pointer to unmarshal, 2. you probably want to retain that variable, or else the whole endeavor is pointless. 3. your code as is will not compile. Are you looking for help? Show actual code, code that can be tested, that runs.

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: Also since all the inner structs are identical you could just define that as a struct and unmarshal into a `map[string]RedisHost` (or whatever you call the struct).

Comment: https://ideone.com/Cl1SCW This is the complete code

Comment: @MayankSharma updated answer to include `map` use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `json.Unmarshal` incorrectly. Please refer to the [JSON docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal).

The proper way to Unmarshal is like so:

```
var conf RedisConfig

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonFile), &conf)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("JSON parsing error:", err)
}

log.Println(conf)
```

And once the typo in the `JSON` is fixed it works:

https://play.golang.org/p/m5LZuDaRbjW

---

To turn the config into a map of addresses, you could use this schema:

```
type RedisMap map[string]RedisAddr

type RedisAddr struct {
    Host    string `json:"host"`
    Port    int    `json:"port"`
    PodHost string `json:"pod_host"`
    PodPort int    `json:"pod_port"`
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/NTou6G_Q8Nc